# Removing files from GIT history

Tags: git, jar, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have a lot of jar files in my git history, and it is taking up a lot of space.
Can I use BFG Repo Cleaner to delete all jar files from my history?

I think running the `--delete-files` command like that `bfg --delete-files .jar <git repo name>.git`, but I am not sure about it.

Is this the right way to do this?
If not, how can I remove all jar files from my history?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really, I am not looking to remove one file from my history, but about a hundred or so, so removing them one at a time is impractical.

Comment: @galmore got your point, I remove my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems to be the good way to do.
BFG is the better tool to remove files in history and taking car of your history.

Be aware that BFG, never touch the last commit (for safety purpose, to be able to always build the last version), so if needed, you will need to remove the jar files yourself from this last commit.

For safety, I highly recommend you to copy your repository before doing something and try the command before verifying if the result suits you.

Comment: I actually want the jars of my last commit to stay there, so that's good. I guess I'll just run it from time to time to clean unused jars from my history.

Comment: I think what you plan to do is a bad practice. Changing the history should be really exceptional and not something that you plan to do from time to time. Perhaps you should find a way to store your jars elsewhere and find a way to download the good version of them. Perhaps also have a look at `git-lfs`

Comment: I want to do it as I am vopying my repository to an offline machine to track changes with git gui, yet those jars require a lot of space which in turn takes time. I only plan to delete unused jars, not files.